# How to retain textbox value until user submit the form

Tags: php

I have some problem here with my online shopping cart in php.
I have several pages in my shopping which is: shop-online.php,cart.php,shipping.php,cart-summary.php

The scenario: There is a textbox at shipping.php where the user has to fill in their shipping details, when user proceed to cart-summary.php and back to shipping.php, the value  should still there, but when user goes back to cart.php, then to shop-online.php then do something there etc pickup another product, goes to cart.php then shipping.php, all the values in the textboxes are gone and the user has to fill it in again.

Code using at shipping.php are $_REQUEST, cart-summary also uses $_REQUEST,

I can't upload my code here due to it being to big.
Please help me, I'm new to php code.

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, are you saying the value in the textbox is disappearing when the user navigates away from the page? If so, you need to either store it in a $_SESSION variable or within the database so you can access the value again.

Comment: Search about `$_SESSION` or cookies.

Comment: @30secondstosam - i can't put in the database because the value may not confirm yet, i guess i've to read the $_SESSION and understand it

Comment: @AhBui have a look at session's then. I've posted an answer below. that should give you some guidance

Comment: you have to keep those details temporarily in database

Answer (score 0):

If looks like you need to store the data you are trying to access. It is up to you as the developer how you do this.

There are a number of ways: through Cookies, Sessions or storing in your database. It may be worth looking up the following:

$_SESSION - http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

$_COOKIE http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php

To use sessions, a very brief and basic example would be:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['myVariable'] = $_POST['textboxValue'];
```

Comment: I'll have a look at it now

Answer (score 0):

You need to use sessions for maintain session variables hold values.

Create a session like

```
 $_SESSION['quantity']=$_POST['quantity'];
```

You can use $_SESSION['quantity'] where ever you need.

Read more about sessions here http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php